# why model.dataValues returns different data with the defined model in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have defined my model with **minimum_reseller_markup**. However, when I query that model, the returned data is not quite what I expected.

Here's my model definition,

```
SupplierCatalog.init({
   supplier_id:  DataTypes.INTEGER,
   product_variant_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
   product_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
   markup: DataTypes.INTEGER,
   minimum_reseller_markup: {
     type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     defaultValue: 0
   },
   status: {
     type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
     defaultValue: true
   },
 }, {
   sequelize,
   modelName: 'SupplierCatalog',
 });
 return SupplierCatalog;
```

and this is the query result I got from `model.dataValues`:

```
{
  id: 74982,
  supplier_id: 35,
  product_variant_id: 80383,
  product_id: 7732,
  markup: 50000,
  minimum_reseller_mark: 45000,
  status: false
}
```

---

field **minimum_reseller_markup** got trimmed.

I tried to re-migrate the model but the query result remains the same.

Any idea what might cause this problem?

Comment: There is no minimum_supplier_markup in the init... There is minimum_reseller_markup

Comment: @digitalniweb sorry, what I meant was minimum_reseller_markup

Comment: The question is what the column name in db really is? minimum_reseller_mark or minimum_reseller_markup? And what database you're using?

Comment: the real column name is minimum_reseller_markup. I am using postgres

Comment: Aren't the data taken from include? https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4158

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall length of identifiers in PostgreSQL is 63 bytes. So I suppose when Sequelize assigns column aliases for column names it can exceed this limit and you will end up with truncated names like you did with `minimum_reseller_markup` when you got it without 2 trailing characters.

You can set the option `minifyAliases` to `true` while creating Sequelize instance. It helps you to avoid such field truncations:

> options.minifyAliases
> boolean
> default: false
> A flag that defines if aliases should be minified (mostly useful to avoid Postgres alias character limit of 64)

See [Sequelize instance constructor](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-constructor-constructor)

and [PostgreSQL limits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/limits.html)